# How do I debug an undefined method for nil class error?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to create a classifier using the cardmagic classifier gem. This is my code:

```
require 'classifier'

classifications = '1007.09', '1006.03'
traindata = Hash["1007.09" => "ADAPTER- SCREENING FOR VALVES VBS", "1006.03" => "ACTUATOR- LINEAR"]

b = Classifier::Bayes.new classifications

traindata.each do |key, value|  
b.train(key, value)
end
```

But when I run this I get the following error:

```
Notice: for 10x faster LSI support, please install http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/classifier-1.3.3/lib/classifier/bayes.rb:27:in `block in train': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/classifier-1.3.3/lib/classifier/bayes.rb:26:in `each'
  from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/classifier-1.3.3/lib/classifier/bayes.rb:26:in `train'
  from C:/_Chris/Code/classifier/smdclasser.rb:13:in `block in <main>'
  from C:/_Chris/Code/classifier/smdclasser.rb:11:in `each'
  from C:/_Chris/Code/classifier/smdclasser.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

This is the source from the gem code:

```
# Provides a general training method for all categories specified in Bayes#new
# For example:
#     b = Classifier::Bayes.new 'This', 'That', 'the_other'
#     b.train :this, "This text"
#     b.train "that", "That text"
#     b.train "The other", "The other text"
def train(category, text)
  category = category.prepare_category_name
  text.word_hash.each do |word, count|
    @categories[category][word]     ||=     0
    @categories[category][word]      +=     count
    @total_words += count
  end
end
```

I am lost where to go to troubleshoot this error, what is the next step I should take?

Comment: I am a big believer in using the debugger when dealing with any sort of problem with my code. Ruby's `rdebug` is very nice, and there is not a single piece of code that doesn't get inspected at that level one time or another as I'm developing. I am anal, but it results in lower bug reports. Check out `gem install rdebug` for Ruby 1.8, or `gem install rdebug19` for 1.9.2.

Comment: I've never used a debugger, I'm writing this using aptana studio. Normally when I have a bug, I follow the code and use my knowledge of the semantics and syntax to see the problem. THen I come to stack or google for the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Classifier::Bayes.new` expects an exploded array of values, rather than a single parameter. For example, notice that the sample code uses:

```
b = Classifier::Bayes.new 'This', 'That', 'the_other'
```

rather than:

```
b = Classifier::Bayes.new ['This', 'That', 'the_other']
```

Pass in the splat version of your `classifications` array and it should work:

```
b = Classifier::Bayes.new *classifications
```

Comment: Another question, with my traindata hash, what if I want to train the classification '1007.09' with multiple sentence values? Hash only allows unique keys and when I add duplicate keys only one is counted using traindata.length. Would i simply create a new hash and train it with each hash rather than trying to use one hash to train it all at once?

Comment: Yes, something like `{"1007.09" => ["first sentence", "second sentence"]}`. You'd also have to update your `each` loop to then iterate over each array value too.